# How to put javascript into php function

Tags: javascript, php

Is is possible to put javascript into a php function? If so could someone please tell me what is wrong with my code? because whenever i put more than one javascript into the php function, my whole functionality will be lost.

```
 <?php

    function headerA($title,$css) {
    $headContent = <<<HEAD
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
            <head>
                <title>$title</title>
                <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="$css" />   

                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function() {
                        $("li").click(function(e) {
                          e.preventDefault();
                          $("li").removeClass("selected");
                          $(this).addClass("selected");
                        });
                    });
                </script> 


            </head>
            <body>
            <div id = "header">

            </div>
    HEAD;
    $headContent .="\n";
    return $headContent;
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Yes, you can, but you should use heredoc properly. `$` is a key character in PHP, which jQuery uses the same. Escape the characters, or avoid using heredoc if you find it difficult to use

Comment: *sidenote:* Better to use HTML5 DOCTYPE; cleaner and more up-to-update.

Comment: And remember- PHP is parsed and executed in one place (on the server), and Javascript is parsed and executed completely separately (in the client's browser).  Even though you can co-mingle JavaScript and PHP on the same source page, they're two completely different languages running in two completely different contexts, and they cannot "talk" directly to each other.

Comment: What you mean by "lost"? Also, "header" is a internal function name, change it to something else. http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: i had already change the "header" to "headerA" for tesing, but it still doesnt work.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the explanation. I appreciate it =).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. Just make sure you:

- place `HEAD;` in the very start of a line (no prepended whitespaces)
- escape the `$` symbols in Javascript.

The `$` symbols in your JavaScript (jQuery) is conflicting with PHP's in-string `$` variable marker. Prepend `$`s will a backslash as follows: `\$`.

Comment: there are no white spaces . and it works just fine if i remove the javascrip tags . But all my functionalities will be lost whenever i put in those javascript tags

Comment: @AuroraBlaze escape the symbol will fix your issue.

Comment: I used another way to fix it. Still thank you very much for the explanations ^^, I appreciate it very much =). I had learned something new from everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the `$`

```
<<<HEAD
  $php_variable
  \$('jQuery');
HEAD;
```

or using output buffer

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
  <?= $php_variable ?>
  $('jQuery');
<?php $head = ob_get_clean(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

do not use header as a function name because it's a predefined function of php.

Heredoc text behaves just like a double-quoted string, without the double quotes. There should be no space before ending `HEAD` line as below.

[check manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

```
<?php 
function header1($title,$css) {
    $headContent = <<<HEAD
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
            <head>
                <title>$title</title>
                <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="$css" />   

                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function() {
                        $("li").click(function(e) {
                          e.preventDefault();
                          $("li").removeClass("selected");
                          $(this).addClass("selected");
                        });
                    });
                </script> 


            </head>
            <body>
            <div id = "header">

            </div>
HEAD;
    $headContent .="\n";
    return $headContent;
    }

    echo header1("title", 'url');
?>
```

Comment: thank you very much for the explanations. I appreciate it. Umm actually I accidentally ate a word "make" while its suppose to be "makeHeader" when I was posting. but now I had changed it to "headerA" for testing and I had found another way to fix the problem. Thank you.